# HttpWebRequest Post WP8

Tags: windows-phone-8, httpwebrequest

First Time Stackoverflow.

Ok, so I have this app I'm making for class project and I'm trying to implement a post request for windows phone 8. I'm kind of a newbie in C# and windows phone dev. This is my first attempt but I have a good understanding of programming principles.

The problem is that Visual Studio returns some exceptions in the debugger console right before or after I assign the textbox's Text property at postData.

Can anyone help me figure out why this happens and/or what material of C#/Windows Phone Dev I should study to understand what's going on.

Any help is greatly appreciated - Thnx in advance.

```
An exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll and wasn't handled before a managed/native boundary
A first chance exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in System.Windows.ni.dll
An exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in System.Windows.ni.dll but was not handled in user code
```

Here is the code.

```
using System;
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using System.Text;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Windows;
    using System.Windows.Controls;
    using System.Windows.Navigation;
    using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
    using Microsoft.Phone.Shell;
    using PhoneApp1.Resources;

    namespace PhoneApp1
    {
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        // Constructor
        public MainPage()
        {

            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private void ButtonFuction(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            var request = HttpWebRequest.Create("http://www.foo.com") as HttpWebRequest;
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            request.BeginGetRequestStream(new AsyncCallback(GetRequestStreamCallback), request);

        }

        private void GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;
            // End the stream request operation
            Stream postStream = request.EndGetRequestStream(asynchronousResult);

            // Create the post data
            string postData = "blah=" + textBlock1.Text + "&blah=" + textBlock2.Text + "&blah=moreblah";

            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);


            postStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
            postStream.Close();

            //Start the web request
            request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(GetResponceStreamCallback), request);

        }

        void GetResponceStreamCallback(IAsyncResult callbackResult)
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)callbackResult.AsyncState;
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(callbackResult);
            using (StreamReader httpWebStreamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                string result = httpWebStreamReader.ReadToEnd();
                //For debug: show results
                Debug.WriteLine(result);
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Why give a -1 for this question and not provide even nominal amount of information to explain why the question may not be completely appropriate? This user is obviously new and is learning the ropes. Jumping on the down-vote without proving information is simply idotic.

Answer (score 1):

First, whenever you encounter this kind of situation (unhandled exception) that leaves you clueless, make sure you catch and examine it.

```
try
{
    // code poops exception
}catch(Exception ex)
{
    // place a breakpoint below
    var thisIsAllYouNeed = ex.ToString();
}
```

You get the exception, all inner exceptions, and a stack trace from that.  Paste that in a question along with the poopy code and you will almost always get an answer (if you don't figure it out on your own).

Your problem is that you haven't specified that you *need to use the network*.  You can't just nab up resources like geolocation, network, SMS, etc without telling the phone owner what you are going to do.  Otherwise, I'd be sending your contact list to my server in Russia while you enjoyed my cute cat app.

So you need to edit your [app manifest file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff769509%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) and specify every controlled resource on the phone you need for your app to work.  You can find [a list of all protected resources here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206936%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).  Read it and see what your app uses.

---

Well, now we know the real issue is threading.  Asynch operations start on one thread and (typically, without doing extra work) end on another.  Therefore `ButtonFuction` starts on one thread (the UI thread), and `GetRequestStreamCallback` runs on another.

UI elements have "thread affinity", meaning that they can only be touched by code executing in the UI thread.  I'll let you search for the reasons why.  You are trying to touch UI elements (`textBlock1.Text`) on a thread that isn't the UI thread.  So, the fix is to stop doing that.

Oh, how?  A couple different ways.  You could use the UI thread's [`Dispatcher`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.aspx) to invoke a method over on the UI thread, but you really want to hold off on this until you are done with all your background thread work.  So, to make this as simple as possible, read out the contents on the UI thread, throw it in a temporary variable, and read that on your background thread.

```
    private void ButtonFuction(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        // Create the post data
        _lolThreading = "blah=" + textBlock1.Text + "&blah=" + textBlock2.Text + "&blah=moreblah";

        var request = HttpWebRequest.Create("http://www.foo.com") as HttpWebRequest;
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.BeginGetRequestStream(new AsyncCallback(GetRequestStreamCallback), request);

    }

    private string _lolThreading;

    private void GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;
        // End the stream request operation
        Stream postStream = request.EndGetRequestStream(asynchronousResult);

        // avoid bad-touching UI stuff
        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_lolThreading);

        postStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        postStream.Close();

        //Start the web request
        request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(GetResponceStreamCallback), request);

    }
```

Now you'll probably want to skip back on the UI thread when done (instead of throwing stuff to `Debug`), so you'll have to use the UI `Dispatcher` (e.g., `textBlock1.Dispatcher`) to `Invoke(() => textBlock1.Text = "some result etc");` (note, it isn't as easy as that, you'll have to research how to invoke first).

Comment: Capability already enabled . Result form try catch:

System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Invalid cross-thread access.
   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.CheckThread()
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.GetValueInternal(DependencyProperty dp)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.GetValueInternal(DependencyProperty dp)
   at System.Windows.Controls.TextBox.get_Text()
   at PhoneApp1.MainPage.GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)

Thanx for the response.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same error, without a clue how to figure out what was wrong, thanks to the answers in here I found out I didn't put all the capabilities required by my app.

Now I learned how to investigate when it happens this :)

Thanks!!!